# Laravel em Linux com NGINX. Erro 500 no browser e Permission denied no log. Uma análise e como resolver da melhor maneira possível?

Tags: linux, laravel-5, nginx, file-permission

Estou instalando uma aplicação em Laravel 5.4 num ambiente Linux Ubuntu 16.04 com NGINX.
Tenho visto que muita gente (assim como eu) sempre se depara com um erro 500 no browser, logo após completada a instalação. O site oficial do [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation), na sua documentação lembra ao usuário para atentar para essa possibilidade:

```
        Directory Permissions

After installing Laravel, you may need to configure some permissions. Directories within the  storage and the bootstrap/cache directories should be writable by your web server or Laravel will not run. If you are using the Homestead virtual machine, these permissions should already be set.
```

## ===================================================

## Erro no browser

## The test.app page isn’t working

## test.app is currently unable to handle this request.

## HTTP ERROR 500

## ===================================================

Verificando o erro no arquivo **test.app-error.log**

```
ila@ig:/var/log/nginx$ gedit test.app-error.log
```

E isso é o que encontro:

```
   2017/03/11 15:10:08 [error] 9306#9306: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: 

   "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  
   Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/home/ila/vhosts/test.app/storage/logs/laravel.log" 
   could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in "/home/ila/vhosts/test.app/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107"

    Stack trace:
    #0 /home/ila/vhosts/test.app/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array)
    #1 /home/ila/vhosts/test.app/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(337): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)
    #2 /home/ila/vhosts/test.app/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(616): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(UnexpectedValueException), Array)
    #3 /home/ila/vhosts/test.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(203): Monolog\Logger->error(Object(UnexpectedValueException), Array)
    #4 /home/ila/vhosts/test.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(114): Illuminate\Log\Writer->write...

    PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  
    Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/home/ila/vhosts/test.app/storage/logs/laravel.log" 
    could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in 
    /home/ila/vhosts/test.app/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107

    Stack trace:
    #0 /home/ila/vhosts/test.app/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array)
    #1 /home/ila/vhosts/test.app/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(337): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)
    #2 /home/ila/vhosts/test.app/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(616): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException), Array)
    #3 /home/ila/vhosts/test.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(203): Monolog\Logger->error(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException), Arr
```

## ===================================================

Ao meu ver esse erro não é muito claro...

Diz que o arquivo `"/home/ila/vhosts/test.app/storage/logs/*laravel.log*"` não pode ser aberto (**could not be opened**) e **Permission denied** para`"/home/ila/vhosts/test.app/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/*StreamHandler.php:107*"`

Temos 2 erros aqui.

1. Não pode abrir um arquivo por falta de permissão
2. A linha 107 do aquivo **StreamHandler.php:107** não foi executada tbm por falta de permissão.

Verificando que função é essa na linha 107 temos esse método:

```
protected function write(array $record)
    {
        if (!is_resource($this->stream)) {
            if (null === $this->url || '' === $this->url) {
                throw new \LogicException('Missing stream url, the stream can not be opened. This may be caused by a premature call to close().');
            }
            $this->createDir();
            $this->errorMessage = null;
            set_error_handler(array($this, 'customErrorHandler'));
            $this->stream = fopen($this->url, 'a');
            if ($this->filePermission !== null) {
                @chmod($this->url, $this->filePermission);
            }
            restore_error_handler();
            if (!is_resource($this->stream)) {
                $this->stream = null;
                throw new \UnexpectedValueException(sprintf('The stream or file "%s" could not be opened: '.$this->errorMessage, $this->url));
            }
        }

        if ($this->useLocking) {
            // ignoring errors here, there's not much we can do about them
            flock($this->stream, LOCK_EX);
        }

        $this->streamWrite($this->stream, $record);

        if ($this->useLocking) {
            flock($this->stream, LOCK_UN);
        }
    }
```

Esse método está criando e gravando algo no sistema.

O fato é que logo após a instalação do laravel o arquivo **laravel.log** não existe dentro de **"/home/ila/vhosts/test.app/storage/logs/"**.
Então ele precisa ser criado para depois se gravar um log de erro.

Então ao meu ver seria mais claro se a mensagem fosse **arquivo laravel.log não encontrado, e prmissão não garantida para ser criado**. É claro que se ele não foi criado não se pode gravar nada nele. Isso é desnecessário.

A mensagem diz que **ele não pode ser lido**! Isso me deixou meio confuso pois pois usuários u(User), grupos g(Group) e outros o(others) podem todos lêr r(Read) ==> d **rwx rwx r-x**.

Veja aqui no terminal:

```
ila@ig:~/vhosts/test.app/storage(master)$ ll
total 20
drwxrwxrwx  5 ila www-data 4096 Mar 11 13:43 ./
drwxr-xr-x 15 ila www-data 4096 Mar 11 14:48 ../
drwxrwxr-x  3 ila www-data 4096 Mar 11 13:43 app/
drwxrwxr-x  5 ila www-data 4096 Mar 11 13:43 framework/
drwxrwxr-x  2 ila www-data 4096 Mar 11 13:43 logs/
```

A maneira de se resolver esse problema, ao meu ver, me parece mais estranha ainda. Note que **ila** e **www-data** (do NGINX) possui ambos permissão **rwx** em "**/home/ila/vhosts/test.app/storage/...**".

Então a conclusão é que não é nem **ila** nem **www-data** que está tentando criar o arquivo **laravel.log** e sim o(others), outros usuários.

Uma abordagem imediata MAS NÃO LÓGICA seria atribuir permissão rwx para o(Others). E é isso que tenho visto o pessoal fazer.

Assim: daremos permissão de escrever w(Write) para o(other) para o diretório storage/ de forma recursiva -R

**ila@ig:~/vhosts/test.app(master)$ sudo chmod guo+w -R storage/** transforma a pasta
"**.../storage/...**" em **rwx rwx rwx => 777**, o que parece **comprometer a segurança da aplicação Laravel**.

## ===================================================

## Verificando

```
ila@ig:~/vhosts/test.app/storage(master)$ ll
total 20
drwxrwxrwx  5 ila www-data 4096 Mar 11 13:43 ./
drwxr-xr-x 15 ila www-data 4096 Mar 11 14:48 ../
drwxrwxrwx  3 ila www-data 4096 Mar 11 13:43 app/
drwxrwxrwx  5 ila www-data 4096 Mar 11 13:43 framework/
drwxrwxrwx  2 ila www-data 4096 Mar 11 13:43 logs/
```

E o arquivo foi criado e o proprietário é o www-data:

```
ila@ig:~/vhosts/test.app/storage/logs(master)$ ll
total 20
drwxrwxrwx 2 ila      www-data 4096 Mar 11 15:26 ./
drwxrwxrwx 5 ila      www-data 4096 Mar 11 13:43 ../
-rw-rw-rw- 1 ila      www-data   14 Mar 11 13:43 .gitignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 4626 Mar 11 23:22 laravel.log
```

Aqui nesse ponto já não existe mais o erro 500 pois o arquivo "laravel.log", já foi criado por alguém **o(Others)**.

NOTE que haverá outros erros semelhantes (Permission denied) se em algum momento
algum usuário não conseguir ler, criar ou executar arquivos dentro de pastas ou arquivos.

Pensando na solução correta e o que encontro pela internet temos 3 opções:

1. Verificar o folder envolvido no erro e garantir permissão **777**?
2. Atribuir **777** para todas as pastas `$ sudo chmod guo+w -R test.app/`?
3. Adicionar u(User) no grupo www-data e vice-versa e garantir permissão rwx para ambos em todos os folders e arquivos? E no caso em questão discutido aqui nesse post foi o usuário o(Others) a origem do problema.

O fato é que dar permissão 777 para **storage/** e qualquer outro arquivo da aplicação resolve o problema, mas qual seria a melhor abordagem para não comprometer a segurança?

## Update

O usuário que está rodando o servidor NGINX.
Geralmente vem configurado por default **www-data**.
Podemos verificar no arquivo de configuração do NGINX em `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` ou rodando o **ps** para ter certeza.

```
ila@ig:~$ grep user /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
user www-data;
ila@ig:~$ ps aux|grep nginx|grep -v grep
root     29809  0.0  0.0 123888  1864 ?        Ss   Mar12   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
www-data 29810  0.0  0.0 124500  5656 ?        S    Mar12   0:11 nginx: worker process
www-data 29811  0.0  0.0 124500  5652 ?        S    Mar12   0:07 nginx: worker process
www-data 29812  0.0  0.0 124336  4860 ?        S    Mar12   0:12 nginx: worker process
www-data 29813  0.0  0.0 124348  5104 ?        S    Mar12   0:15 nginx: worker process
www-data 29814  0.0  0.0 124336  4796 ?        S    Mar12   0:12 nginx: worker process
```

1. [How to fix Error: laravel.log could not be opened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411520/how-to-fix-error-laravel-log-could-not-be-opened)

Comment: Você tem certeza que o usuário do nginx é o `www-data`? Poderia postar o pedaço do seu arquivo de configuração que define isso? Você pode ver esta opção na [documentação](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#user).

Comment: Oi, fiz um update com a informação do usuário do NGINX

Comment: > Porque não usar o [ISPConfig3](https://gist.github.com/jniltinho/dcacbfbccf6822795e6b) com Nginx, assim você vai saber como é a configuração do Nginx no ISPConfig3, faz um teste simples em uma VM.

Comment: Olá conseguiu a solução para esse "problemão"?
Se sim... Responda sua própria pergunta!